# Reading of 管 as in "かん" vs "くだ" and its meaning regarding those two readings

Tags: kanji, readings, false-etymology

こんにちは。

After reading jisho, here's some of the information that I found:

管 (kun: くだ  on: カン)

Interestingly, if you search the details, jisho lists 管 read as **【カン】** and 
 **【かん】**, even though the meaning is the same i.e.: pipe or tube.

**My first guess:**

> Pipe as in cylindrical/tubular pvc pipe.
>
> While tube as in wind instrument.

**かん【管】**

> [共通する意味] ★円筒形で中が空になったもの。
>
> [使い方]〔管〕(くだ)▽ガスの管を引く〔管〕(かん)

**くだ【管】**

> [共通する意味] ★円筒形で中が空になったもの。
>
> [使い方]〔管〕(くだ)▽ガスの管を引く〔管〕(かん)

**[Source](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/thsrs/%E7%AE%A1+/m0u/)**

The explanation is totally the same, that is 'empty-shelled' pvc pipe.

However, it differs on the other entries:

**(Kun reading)**

> **管轄** 【カンカツ】 jurisdiction, control
>
> **配管** 【ハイカン】 plumbing, piping
>
> **移管** 【イカン】 transfer of control

while

**(On reading)**

> **管** 【かん】 pipe, tube
>
> **管狐** 【くだぎつね】 mythological pipe fox, stoat
>
> **手練手管** 【てれんてくだ】 wiles, art of coaxing
>
> **手管** 【てくだ】 wiles, trick, artifice, coquetry, lover (male) (esp. of a prostitute)

Entries from Wiktionary have more explanation:

**管 (hiragana くだ, rōmaji kuda)**

**Meaning:**

> 1. a pipe or tube, such as that made of bamboo, wood, metal, or rubber
> 2. a shuttle for weaving with a loom (from the way the earliest shuttles were made from bamboo tubes)
> 3. the central axis of a spindle for winding the thread
> 4. short for 管の笛 (くだのふえ), a kind of small pipe or flute used for signalling during a battle, similar to a fife
> 5. an agricultural tool, used to gather up cut rice stalks
> 6. short for 管狐 (くだぎつね), a kind of mythical fox roughly the size of a weasel, that would live in bamboo stalks and make prophesies of the
>      future.

**[Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%AE%A1)**

**My questions:**

> 1. Why is that there are two exactly same readings as 'kan' in both kun and on reading while retaining the same meaning? i.e.: pipe/tube
>
>    Usually, kanji has different readings and different meanings which
>      are then categorized by 'kun' and 'on' reading.
> 2. Is there any etymological difference or similarity that makes these two readings 'different' or 'similar'?
> 3. Is this related to: that **管** originated from **筦** in Chinese?
> 4. If this 管 is used, which is preferable and more natural, かん or くだ? My guess is かん, because くだ feels more 'foreign' to my intuition. Is
>      this correct?
> 5. Is there something that I miss? Thank you for all your answers! (*´∀｀*)

**Based on [source(jisho.org)](https://jisho.org/search/%23kanji%20%E7%AE%A1)**

Comment: かん is the onyomi. The answer to your first question is that Jisho listing かん as a kunyomi for 管 is just a mistake.

Comment: What @Leebo said.  Jisho.org is very ... messy, and poorly maintained.  Take its entries with a grain of salt (i.e., don't trust them entirely).

Comment: Jisho.org uses EDICT/JMDICT data so if you find errors, you can report them or request edits via the web interface on edrdg.org, e.g.: http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&e=55744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally use くだ. The reading of かん is a kind of jargon among construction industry.